# creating different edit screens for different roles

Tags: custom-post-types, dashboard, capabilities, post-editor, user-roles

I have created a custom post type and custom role, created the proper capabilities and assigned them so the new role and see and edit their own ctp's entries... but I'd like to create a customized edit screen for this role and for administrator roles.

E.g.: the role "custom_user" can edit the title, edit the attached image, etc; can see the value of another custom field (e.g.: 'approved_for_publication'), but can't edit that field.

A regular admin would get the regular edit screen, with all fields, but "custom_user" would get the modified version.

Same thing with the list view in the dashboard for that CTP. The admin would get certain columns, but the "custom_user" would get a slightly modified set of columns (e.g. the admin would get a "author" column, but "custom_user" wouldn't, since he'd only be seeing his own posts.

Any pointer on how to go about it? Searching about it I only find howtos to create custom roles and capabilities, or custom post types; which are things I already have covered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it for different edit pages for different roles.

In my method resposible for rendering the field I have:

```
if ( count( array_intersect( $allowed_editors, $user->roles ) ) < 1 )
   $readonly = 'readonly';
```

Which I later use to either set the input field as readonly or add/remove classes before rendering it.

Still working for the different columns, I'll update when finished. I guess that this is more useful than just deleting my question... :P